# c# how to find which tab is open for user in selenium 4.4.3

Tags: c#, selenium

if the user opens 4 tabs, how can my code find out which tab is currently open for the user to switch to that tab?
The codes I use for this work:

```
private void Timer1_Tick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = driver.WindowHandles.Count();

    foreach (var handle in driver.WindowHandles) 
    {                                        
        int test = driver.WindowHandles.IndexOf(handle);
        which = // which tab active until the switchto  it???

        driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[which]);
    }                  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a very simple example, note that the
`driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab)` works with Selenium 4 and later versions:

```
string[] searchEngines = { "http://www.bing.com/", "https://google.com", "https://duckduckgo.com" };

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(searchEngines[0]);
var firstTab = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(searchEngines[1]);
var secondTab = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;


driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(searchEngines[2]);
var thirdTab = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;

// Here we select the tab we want by passing the string 
// identifier we already got by calling `driver.CurrentWindowHandle` 
driver.SwitchTo().Window(firstTab);
```

Comment: thank you . But this code only opens a new tab. I want my code to recognize which tab is active or focused for the user and then switch to that code.The user may have opened the tabs by right-clicking to open link new tab